# How can I adjust the ACL of existing posts on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I have 4.5K posts in my **Parse.com** application. Now the most of them have only read access but I want to adjust all these records to have read/write or add an extra role with the read/write access.

The roles part is not really clear for me. How Can I create a subscriber role for example and attach users to this.

Do I have to do this all in cloud code from **Parse.com**?

Comment: What to u want to do exactly?
Do you want to change the ACL permission from 'read' to 'read and write'??

Comment: yes I want to change them all to read / write for now. and later on  i want to create a group who is able to do this

Comment: You can do that in cloud code or in normal JS file.
First you need to query all the rows for which you want to update. Then change their ACL permissions. Then save all the objects again. Refer to this
https://parse.com/questions/change-acl-on-objects-only-after-user-signup

Answer (score 0):

For the `_User` class, the default ACL is read public and written only by that user particularly. For other classes you created, its default setting is public read/write. You have to understand this before heading to Role.

For your case, you probably need to write a simple script in order to modify the ACL individually.

Role is similar to ACL. Because every single objects has ACL and it's so difficult to modify them one by one. Role is created for grouping users who have common access privileges to your **Parse.com** data. Following is a story telling from **Parse.com** which is really great:

> For example, in your application with curated content, you may have a
>   number of users that are considered "Moderators" and can modify and
>   delete content created by other users. You may also have a set of
>   users that are "Administrators" and are allowed all of the same
>   privileges as Moderators, but can also modify the global settings for
>   the application. By adding users to these roles, you can ensure that
>   new users can be made moderators or administrators, without having to
>   manually grant permission to every resource for each user.

Comment: Hi Lucas thanks for your reply ! only i cannot find any code how to create the roles and how to change all the existing ACLs in my posts.

Comment: Hi Maybe i was not really clear what my intensions are. i have 4.5 k posts. and I just want to change the ACL of these posts once. to read write. the documenation is not very clear about this... so thats why I ended up here to find somebody who could help me out with some code how to do this.. of course I have read all the documentation pages but those are not really helping. so referring to the guide is not my solution